# Populate google chart with not fixed column number

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, logic

I'm currently making some charts and I'm blocked because I really don't see how I can solve this problem.

Fisrt, I have created my columns like this :

```
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Months');
    var techlist = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.techs));
    for(var j=0; j<@ViewBag.nbTechs;j++)
    {
        data.addColumn('number', techlist[j]);
    }
```

I create them this way because the number of column is not fixed and as you my first column is for month(in string) and others are numbers.

Now to populate this chart, I have a List of List of integer ( `List<List<int>>`). I have 12 lists in my list ( one for each month ) witch is populate with the numbers needed in my chart.

So basicly I want to have something like this :

```
        foreach(List<List<int>>){ 
                switch(index of List<int>){
                      case 1 : data.addRows(['january', first list of List<List<int>>)
                      case 2 : data.addRows(['february', second list of List<List<int>>)
                      ...
                      case 12 : data.addRows(['december', twelfth list of List<List<int>>)
                }        
        }
```

If someone have any idea how it can be done , I will be so happy :)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Stop using `ViewBag` and use a view model to pass the data to your view - it would have (say) `string Month`and `List<int> Values` and then you pass a collection of that model to the view (12 items) and then use `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` to serialize the collection to a javascript array

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok I will try this way !

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok so now I have a list of graphstats(string + list of int) and I pass it to the view and encode it in Json but I don't know how to use it in addRows :s I've tried many things but none is working :(

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've done `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` in my page and i get  `[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]` ... I don't know why it's empty because I checked and I'm not sending it empty from my controller

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry I forgot to edit but I found my mistake ! I'm pretty new in C# and I thought attributes in object where public by default but it's not the case that's why my JSON was empty !